# How to output warnings to the console during a build in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings

How do I output custom warnings to the console in Xcode? I want to do this to remind myself that I'm in a particular build mode.

I tried `#warning "Hello World"` but I don't see it in the console.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

I don't want to use `NSLog` because I am already using it to log a bunch of stuff so when I use NSLog for warnings, it is difficult to see all the warnings.

Comment: To be clear, are the messages for the build window - if so "#warning ..." works?

Comment: I don't see my warning messages using `#warning` in the build console.

Answer (score 5):

**#warning directive**

The **#warning directive** is to see the message on the compiler. This is very handy to know that something must be changed before deploying or simply to remember to change a piece of code that can be improved (but you don't have the time to do so now). (go to View -> Navigators -> Show Issue Navigator on your project and you will the see the list of warnings). These messages will not appear on the console.

**The Apple System Log facility**

What you want is to show a warning to the console while the app is running and here is where **The Apple System Log facility** comes to the rescue.

You have 8 logging levels:

- 0 Emergency.
- 1 Alert
- 2 Critical
- 3 Error
- 4 Warning
- 5 Notice
- 6 Info
- 7 Debug

Code sample:

```
#include <asl.h>
...
asl_log(NULL, NULL, ASL_LEVEL_INFO, "Hello World!");
```

Since I was in the same situation than you once, and to make things simple, I use this wrapper https://github.com/MikeWeller/MWLogging in all my projects so my debug errors won't show when I send my App to the App Store but other critical error will.

Update: Now with Swift I use this debug log framework https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSLog

In state of your warning use something like:

```
NSLog(@"Hello World");
```

Or you can use the standard C printf function:

```
printf("Hello World");
```

If you want to be printed on stderr you can use fprintf redirected to stderr.

Comment: I don't want to use `NSLog` because I am already using it to log a bunch of stuff so when I use NSLog for warnings, it is difficult to see all the warnings.

Comment: then you can use the standard C printf function. don't forget objective c is build on top of C.